# Curl's CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION callback returns dlnow > dltotal

Tags: c++, curl

I've been using CURL for all HTTP communication. I need a to know when the server is done sending me a response. According to the CURL documentation CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION is designed to do just that.

However, every time the callback function get hit, all the arguments are either all 0, or all 0 besides dlnow which is 233. This is not the expected behavior, and i haven't found people with a similar problem after googling.

Callback initiation:

```
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION, CLibCurlThreadTask::CurlProgress);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0L);
```

Callback function:

```
int CLibCurlThreadTask::CurlProgress(void *clientp,   curl_off_t dltotal,   curl_off_t dlnow,   curl_off_t ultotal,   curl_off_t ulnow)
{   
if( dltotal > 0 || dlnow > 0 || ultotal > 0 || ulnow > 0)
    {
        CryLogAlways("UP: %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T " of %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T "  DOWN: %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T " of %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T "\r\n", ulnow, ultotal, dlnow, dltotal);
    }   
    return CURLE_OK;
}
```

Output:

> UP: 0 of 0  DOWN: 233 of 0
>
> UP: 0 of 0  DOWN: 233 of 0
>
> UP: 0 of 0  DOWN: 233 of 0
>
> UP: 0 of 0  DOWN: 233 of 0

Comment: Does it do this for all requests, or only some? Could it be that some requests don't provider a `Content-Length`-header?

Comment: @zenzelezz We do some 10-20 requests, and all the calls to CurlProgress are either all arguments 0 or all 0 besides dlnow which is 233.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a problem of 32bits / 64bits platform.

See: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=29767.0