# Using libcurl's download progress function from C++

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

Working on a small application using `libcurl`. Downloaded the source tar file and compiled and all fine till here.

following this [progress function](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/progressfunc.html) example which isn't working as it is supposed to.

set the callback function for showing the progress

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION, &FileTransfer::progressCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
```

which is

```
int FileTransfer::progressCallback(void* clientp, curl_off_t dlTotal, curl_off_t dlNow, curl_off_t ulTotal, curl_off_t ulNow)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "UP: %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T " of %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T
              "  DOWN: %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T " of %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T
              "\r\n",
              ulNow, ulTotal, dlNow, dlTotal);
    return 0;
}
```

which is printing

```
........
UP: 4233172 of 0  DOWN: 0 of 2588672
UP: 4233172 of 0  DOWN: 0 of 2588672
UP: 4233172 of 0  DOWN: 0 of 2588672
UP: 4233172 of 0  DOWN: 0 of 2588672
.........
```

and is wrong. I'm not uploading anything (where is 4233172 coming from) and `dlTotal` is showing `dlNow` value (i.e., downloaded bytes) and `dlNow` is always 0.

Also, `CURLOPT_XFERINFODATA` isn't working. As per the documentation, this could be anything and I tried passing `this`, some random struct, and an int and nothing seems to be passed to the callback function (`void* clientp` is always null)

Using the latest `libcurl` version 7.52.1

Comment: Present your [MCVE] please, and don't tag irrelevant languages.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `libcurl` is a `c` library and using it in a `c++` app. Which is the wrong tag please? thanks.

Comment: `FileTransfer::progressCallback` is a non-static member function, right? Try wrapping it and passing a pointer to a plain old function instead.

Comment: @ramtheconqueror: You are writing C++, so tag it [tag:c++]. Doesn't matter what libcurl is written in, because you are not developing libcurl.

Comment: @Phillip: If it were non-static I don't think this would compile.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit only with `-Wpmf-conversions -Werror`, elsewise it only throws a warning. Converting any pointer to `void*` is perfectly valid in C.

Comment: @Phillip: But taking the address of a non-static member function does not yield a function pointer type.

Comment: @Phillip: Ah but `curl_easy_setopt` is generic. Okay then yes I think that's probably what the OP has done. See, this is why we require **[MCVE]s**.

Comment: Did you check the following post ["Curl's CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION callback returns dlnow > dltotal"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803965/curls-curlopt-xferinfofunction-callback-returns-dlnow-dltotal) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

libcurl is a C library, so it doesn't know anything about C++ member functions. And if you just put a C++ method as callback, the code will think there's a hidden 'this' pointer passed as the first argument while as libcurl is a C library it doesn't send a 'this' and then your arguments get all wrong.

You can overcome this "limitation" with relative ease using a static
member function that is passed a pointer to the class:

```
 // f is the pointer to your object.
 static size_t YourClass::func(void *buffer, size_t sz, size_t n, void *f)
 {
   // Call non-static member function.
   static_cast<YourClass*>(f)->nonStaticFunction();
 }

 // This is how you pass pointer to the static function:
 curl_easy_setopt(hcurl, CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION, YourClass::func);
 curl_easy_setopt(hcurl, CURLOPT_XEFRINFODATA, this);
```